# How to obtain an array without repeated values with one function

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop, random

I want to create two arrays, none of them can have repeated values and if posible I look for an answer in the same loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++){//MAX=vector's number of values
            scanf("%d", &vector[i]);//reads the number from the keyboard
            while(j!=i){//Looks for each vector[i] if there is a vector[j], with j<i, with that value already. j starts at 0
                    if(vector[j]==vector[i]){
                            printf("\nWrite another number\n");
                            scanf("%d",&vector[i]);
                            j=0;
                    }
                    else
                            j++;
            }
    }
```

for this second loop I look for the same result, a non repeated set of values, but with random numbers.

```
for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++){
            vector[i]=(rand()%MAX-MIN+1)+MIN;
            while(j!=i){
                   if(vector[j]==vector[i]){
                            vector[i]=(rand()%MAX-MIN+1)+MIN;;
                            j=0;
                    }
                    else
                            j++;
            }
    }
```

I have been trying to come with a way to generate a random number between two intervals, like (2,10)U(12,20), so whenever you found a repeated value the next random number does not contain it, but I can not find any way to do it that way.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To generate a random number in the union of two intervals you could use:

```
int n = rand() % (TOTAL_INTERVAL_MEMBERS-1) + LOWEST_INTERVAL_MEMBER;
if (n > MEMBERS_IN_LOWEST_VALUE_INTERVAL) n += INTERVAL_DIFFERENCE;
```

for your example intervals of (2,10) & (12,20) it would be:

```
int n = rand() % 17 + 2;
if (n > 9) n += 2;
```

if you instead want to find a value between the intervals you can simply use

```
int n = rand() % (DIFFERENCE_BETWEEN_INTERVALS - 1) + END_OF_LOWEST_VALUE_INTERVAL+1;
```

which with your example would be:

```
int num = rand() % ((12-10) - 1) + 10 + 1;
```

Comment: Don't we need brackets in `rand() % (TOTAL_INTERVAL_MEMBERS-1 + LOWEST_INTERVAL_MEMBER)` ?

Comment: We do but around the (TOTAL_INTERVAL_MEMBERS-1), my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If the range of numbers is not too large, you might want to create an array of valid numbers, and select randomly from that.

```
int valid[VALID_MAX + 1];  // Assuming range is 0 to VALID_MAX.

for (int valid_idx = 0;valid_idx < VALID_MAX + 1;valid_idx++) {
    valid[valid_idx] = valid_idx;
}
```

To select:

```
valid_top = VALID_LEN;
for (int vector_idx = 0;vector_idx < MAX;vector_idx++) {
    // Select from 0 to valid_top-1.
    const int valid_idx = rand() % valid_top;
    vector[vector_idx] = valid[valid_idx];

    // Don't allow it to be selected again.
    // Replace this value with the top (still valid),
    // and shrink the valid list so the top value is
    // not listed twice.
    valid[valid_idx] = valid[valid_top - 1];
    valid_top--;
}
```

If you happen to randomly select the top value, this still works - top value is copied over itself, then disappears when valid_top is decremented.

Anyway, this will take a short constant time, rather than looping through all previous numbers, and re-trying if it happens to be a duplicate. But only works for fairly small number ranges.